# Positioning a link (button) that is off screen

Tags: html, css, position

I was styling a webpage for a new company and had the header perfect, except we didn't have a logo yet so i put a  in its place. Now i replaced the  with the  but the call to action button under it has been pushed off screen. I know there are millions of tutorials on positioning on the internet but i'm seriously stuck!

```
<body>
<header>
   <nav>
       <div class="row">
            <ul class="main-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Quote</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
       </div>
   </nav>
    <div class="hero-text-box">
       <img src="img/test.png" width="500px" height="500px" alt="test">
       <a class="btn" href="#">Get a Quick Quote</a>
    </div>
</header>

header {
background-image: url(img/hero2.jpg);
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
height: 100vh;
}

.hero-text-box {
position: absolute;
width: 1140px;
top: 20%;
left: 60%;
}
```

Comment: post some code for help

Comment: Could you please reword your question?

Comment: i tried to post jsfiddle but i had issues with the images. there is a background image that did not fill the header and the logo is a png but had a black background around it

Comment: Auguste, basically there is a link that is styled as a button that is floating off screen and I am not able to move it at all

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of positioning elements. since you did not specify where you wanted the button to be positioned I will presume you want it to be centered. An easy (and backwards compatible) way of doing it is:

```
.button { 
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: -25px;
}
```

*the reason we are using a negative margin is because positioning is left aligned, meaning that top: 0 and left: 0 is in the top left of the element. Therefore, when we do left:50% it is offset by 25 more pixels than it should be if we want the element to be centered*

Make sure that the button element does not have any parents that have a position attribute. If the parent element of the button does has a position attribute it will place the button element relative to that parent element. Hope this is of help to you, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do the trick.

```
.hero-text-box {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    z-index:1;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
}
```